# Spark job fails when using checkpointing if a class change in the job

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have my application jar sitting in HDFS which defines long-running Spark Streaming job and I am using checkpoint dir also in HDFS. Every time I have any changes to the job, I go delete that jar and upload a new one.

Now if I upload a new jar and delete checkpoint directory it works fine. But if I don't delete the checkpoint directory, I get an error like:

> imestamp="2016-05-13T18:49:47,887+0000",level="WARN",threadName="main",logger="org.apache.spark.streaming.CheckpointReader",message="Error reading checkpoint from file hdfs://myCheckpoints/application-1/checkpoint-1463165355000",exception=**"java.io.InvalidClassException: some.package.defined.here.ConcreteClass; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7808345595732501156, local class serialVersionUID = 1574855058137843618**

I have changed the 'ConcreteClass' from my last implementation and that's what's causing the issue.

I have 2 main questions:

1. **How to fix this?** I know adding `private static long serialVersionUID = 1113799434508676095L;` might fix it, but I don't want to add this to all classes, since any class can change between current and next version. Anything better?
2. **What all does checkpoint directory store?** Does it store all classes from previous jar? Or just their name and serialVersionUID? [This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing) doesn't give much detail on internals of checkpointing. It's size is only ~ 6Mb.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: what version of Spark Streaming are you using? This is a known issue < (I think 1.6).  Do you really need checkpointing?  (I avoid it at all costs)

Comment: I have 1.6.1. I use checkpointing for Kafka offset management so that if the job is restarted (due to machine failure/deploying new application jar), it'll start consuming messages from wherever it left off from. What alternative do you propose to checkpointing for Kafka offset management?

Comment: For a project, I implemented Offset management by writing offsets and timestamps to Cassandra. Let's you recover from last  or any time-window. Worked really well and didn't tie our hands with the checkpoint (also a lot faster)

Comment: Interesting, I was only wondering if you have sample code online somewhere? Also, what other issues you found with checkpointing?

Comment: it was a private project. No code around from that. Not on my hands either, but it's not very hard. Use the 'offset management' interface as explained here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers and store them to cassandra in an appropriate schema. When you restart your job, read the latest from Cassandra. You will need to bootstrap reading the offsets (earliest,latest - depending on your requirements) from Kafka the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @maasg, I'll give it a try

Comment: @maasg Are you able to achieve `Exactly Once` semantics with this alternative method?

Comment: In my understating even with Checkpointing you can't. Spark writes checkpoint at end of each batch and if your job fails in between the batch it'll restart the batch if job is alive or if job is restarted then from previous checkpoint.

Comment: @maasg Good suggestion, I implemented my own offset tracking from the master, and it seems to work fine. Did you save the offsets from driver at end of each batch (i am doing that)? or from workers whenever they are done with a message from a partition - to achieve 'exactly once' semantics?